# Server (http://localhost:8888/) not found (MAMP)

Tags: localhost, mamp

I have created a wordpress.org site hosted on Mamp, but I can only access it from my laptop. I sent the link to a friend and get the message "This site can't be reached". Please help. I am a novice at this kind of thing. My site address is http://localhost:8888/the_models_collector but on my oh-admin it says the serve is localhost:8889.

Comment: localhost is not visible outside your computer, you need to share it with public IP like http://your_public_ipp:8888/the_models_collector

Comment: Sorry this might come across as very stupid, but where do I get my public IP?

Comment: https://whatismyipaddress.com , however not necessary your friend can access your server as there might be firewall etc involved

Comment: Shailesh, I found it but it does not work still. I entered public_ip:8888/the_modles_collector

Comment: nevermind, I would suggest reading about IP and Networking

Comment: @pilara: What OS are you running on? Windows or Mac OS?

Comment: @J.Murray, its a macOsMojave